# Issue loading two files while uploading a package to PyPi

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, hdf5, pypi, setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
   def readme():
        with open('README.md') as f:
        README=f.read()
    return README

setup(
      name="hello_world",
      version="0.0.1",
      description='Just an another Python Package',
      long_description= readme(),
      long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
      url='https://github..........',
      author='import666',
      author_email='sigmamale@gmail.com',
       classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",],
      packages=['orig'],
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=['pandas','numpy','scikit-learn==0.24.1','scikit-optimize','matplotlib','xgboost'],
      entry_points={
          "console_scripts":[
              'blah=orig.happy.world'] 
          },
      python_requires=">=3.6",
      )
```

The files I wanted to upload to PyPi are `happy.py` and `world.h5` and happy works only if `world.h5`  is available. blah is a folder that has a folder named '`orig`' and orig contains `happy.py` and `world.h5` which is placed in `c:\users\`.
The error is in the line

```
console_scripts":'blah=orig.happy.world']
```

I am trying to publish my first package and I am not sure how to write this line of code.

Comment: Please show the error or explain it. Also, explain what is the code included in the question has to do with your problem since it doesn't seem to be uploading anything.

Comment: The `pip install hello_world` runs perfectly fine, it is downloading all the required packages and respective versions. The problem arises when I try to do `import happy_world` It gives the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'happy_world'`So I assumed that there was an error in the above line since it is dealing with the directory of my files. The above code is a `setup.py` for uploading my package on PyPi.

Comment: The problem you're explaining can be only related to the "pip install" and your interpreter settings etc. Also, your original question is not reflecting any of these information. Please edit your original question, and there, explain what you want to do, show the code and the error that you're seeing when running the code.